# No module named flask while running uWSGI

Tags: python, import, flask, uwsgi

I have a very simple flask app (myflaskapp.py):

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "<span style='color:red'>I am app 1</span>"
```

If I run:

```
uwsgi --http-socket :3031 --plugin python --wsgi-file myflaskapp.py --callable app
```

I get the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myflaskapp.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
ImportError: No module named flask
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
```

and I don't understand why. I have flask installed (pip install flask). If I run ipython and import flask it also works there. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: ensure the python version used by uwsgi is the same you have used for flask (or for building the test virtualenv). The python version is printed on uWSGI startup logs

Comment: Yeah the versions are slightly different: 2.7.5 for uWSGI and 2.7.3 in the virtualenv.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In the end what worked for me was adding -H /path/to/virtualenv to the uWSGI command:

```
uwsgi --http-socket :3031 --plugin python --wsgi-file myflaskapp.py --callable app -H /path/to/virtualenv
```

I also had different Python versions in the virtualenv and for uWSGI. I'm still investigating if this could cause any problems.

Comment: I am 100% sure it is because of different python verisons. I had the same issue which got resolved after I used python3 for both venv and uwsgi

Answer (score 3):

I ran into same problem once, as there was some version conflict

then instead of using pip to install uwsgi I did it by my package manager
On ubuntu machine,

```
sudo apt-get install uwsgi
```

Also check and run myflaskapp.py without uwsgi that is by using app.run() in your code

*Note : That will be by werkzeug server.

Answer (score 3):

I faced similar problem and found the reason that if we have a module installed in a virtual environment(Flask in this case) we may need to add --virtualenv path in addition to the basic instructions needed to run a Flask app using uWSGI

So the instruction according the uWSGI document would be:

```
uwsgi --http-socket :3031 --plugin python --wsgi-file myflaskapp.py --callable app --virtualenv /path_to_virtualenv
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just add one line into you .ini file:

```
home=/your/virtual/env/path
```